# How to create an update setup for a Vb.net application

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, desktop-application, setup-project

I Created the setup for my vb.Net appliaction and installed it on the client systems. The application uses MS Access as the database. So i manually added the file to Setup project under its application directory.

Now I have an update for that appliaction. So how can i create an update setup for the application. And I need to keep the Database file as it is ( Dont Delete or Dont install new copy).

[image]
Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest solution is to use backup and restore custom actions:

- backup the original file before the installation starts (before [InstallFiles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa369503%28VS.85%29.aspx) action)
- restore it after installation is finished (after InstallFiles action)

To update an older version you can use a [major upgrade](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa369786%28VS.85%29.aspx):

- increase the ProductVersion of your package
- change the ProductCode

This way the new version will automatically uninstall the old one during install.